# Setting up poker bot

Tags: python, bots

I'm a new "hobbyist" software developer / tech guy and have been running several interesting pilot projects so far. Currently I'm interested about poker after reading some discussions around those and found an interesting open source project https://github.com/dickreuter/Poker.

For some reason I'm having issues even getting the project up and running, since there some kind of module error popping up.

What I have been doing is the following:

**1. Cloning the repository :** git clone https://github.com/dickreuter/Poker.git

**2. Setting up venv accordingly :** directly from PyCharm

**3. Installing mac requirements to venv :** pip3 install -r requirements_mac.txt

**4. Trying to run main.py :** python3 Users//Desktop/poker_ai/Poker/poker/main.py

Now it gives me this error:

```
  File "/Users//Desktop/poker_ai/Poker/poker/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    from poker.restapi_local import local_restapi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Poker'
```

Am I missing something in the installation steps that I'm doing?
Really appreciate all kind of help! :)

Comment: Are you certain that its 'Poker' with uppercase and not 'poker'? (as there is no uppercase in the code and lowercase makes more sense to not be able to find the poker module)

Comment: Yes I tried with Poker as well without any success...

Comment: To clarify: is there `No module named 'Poker'` is the error message or `No module named 'poker'`? You likely need to add the parent dictionary of poker to your PATH variable or use `cd` to navigate into the dictionary where the `poker` folder is, so that in working directory is the lowercase poker folder.